# save and load Checkbox states

Tags: java, android

I'm doing an shopping list apps and i'm trying to save the states of the item checkbox when the user click on the previous button on the phone i'm using th onPause method to save the states and the sharedPreference but for a reason that i dont understand when i come back to my list all the checkbox are checked i know it come from my loadSelections method but i dont know how to fix it can you help me please ?

I try to figure it out but i'm new to java and android so its hard for me.

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;

public class FruitList_Activity extends AppCompatActivity  {

```
private ListView fruitsList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFruit;
private Button btn_Delete;
private Button btn_SelectAll;
public  ArrayList<String>  savedItemList = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_fruit_list_);

    fruitsList = findViewById(R.id.list_Fruits);
    fruitsList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    btn_Delete = findViewById (R.id.btn_delete);
    CreateActivity.itemsFruit = FileHelper.readData(this);

    adapterFruit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, CreateActivity.itemsFruit);
    fruitsList.setAdapter(adapterFruit);
    LoadSelections();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // always handle the onPause to make sure selections are saved if user clicks back button
    SaveSelections();
    super.onPause();
}

private void LoadSelections() {
    // if the selections were previously saved load them
    SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settingsActivity.contains(CreateActivity.itemsFruit.toString())) {
        String savedItems = settingsActivity.getString(CreateActivity.itemsFruit.toString(), "");
        CreateActivity.itemsFruit.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));
        int count = this.fruitsList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String currentItem = (String) this.fruitsList.getAdapter().getItem(i);
            if (CreateActivity.itemsFruit.contains(currentItem)) {
                this.fruitsList.setItemChecked(i, true);
            } else { this.fruitsList.setItemChecked(i, false);
        }
    }
    }
}


private void SaveSelections() {
    // save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the user
    SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settingsActivity.edit();
    String savedItems = getSavedItems();
    prefEditor.putString(CreateActivity.itemsFruit.toString(), savedItems);
    prefEditor.commit();
}
private String getSavedItems() {
    String savedItems = "";
    int count = fruitsList.getAdapter().getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (fruitsList.isItemChecked(i)) {
            if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                savedItems += "," + fruitsList.getItemAtPosition(i);
            } else {
                savedItems += fruitsList.getItemAtPosition(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return savedItems;
}
```

}

I would like the states of my checkbox to be save and load  properly.

Thanks

Comment: Consider using local room database instead of shared preferences. Shared preferences are intended for small key,value data.

Comment: I want to try both but i wanted to use shared preference first since it wont be heavy data but if i cant get my save to work properly i wont be able to do it in in Database etheir...